# InfluxDB merge different Field Value to single printout

Tags: influxdb

I want to get the one line printout by mix/merge different field value, like the following , (Mix or Merge is method what I assume)

```
select mix(value) from test group by “name”
name: test
tags: name=“case1”
time                  mix/merge

1970-01-01T00:00:00Z  failed,passed,skipped


select * from test group by “name”
name: test
tags: name=“case1”
time                            caseAuthor caseName caseResult value

2018-07-20T03:51:42.599533888Z  mike       case1    pass       1
2018-07-20T03:51:42.690955475Z  mike       case1    failed     2
2018-07-20T03:51:42.723272883Z  mike       case1    skipped    3
```

thanks for any help
BRs
/Yijun

Answer (score 0):

As for v1.6 there is no "join" or "concat" [aggregation function](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/functions/) in InfluxQL. All you can do is running

```
SELECT DISTINCT("caseResult") 
FROM "test" 
GROUP BY “name”
```

and then join values by "comma" separator in each group with some bash script or the programming language executing a query.

And actually, even though InfluxDB supports various data types (e.g. strings and booleans) InfluxQL support for processing data of types other then numeric is very-very poor in my opinion...

Comment: thanks @WindyFields, but such printout will show 3 lines still,  what i want is one line which combine caseResult as one Value, which seems not possible for influxdb.  thanks all the same